# React-router - redirect on load?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm new to React development and I'm not sure how to handle this.

I have a simple app with routes, it looks like this:

```
<Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={MainComponent} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardComponent} />
      <Route path="/users" component={UsersComponent} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={AdminComponent} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

When I go to localhost:3000/myApp/index.html my `MainComponent` loads as expected, it holds main layout of the site, navigation and so forth.

Then I have to click on "Dashboard" to switch to `DashboardComponent`, "Users" to move to `UsersComponent` and "Admin" to load `AdminComponent`, these are loaded next to the navigation from `MainComponent`.

So it goes like this:

```
localhost:3000/myApp = MainComponent 
localhost:3000/dashboard = MainComponent + DashboardComponent
localhost:3000/users = MainComponent + UsersComponent
localhost:3000/admin = MainComponent + AdminComponent
```

What I want to achieve is to never load `MainComponent` alone (as it holds nothing excepting navigation), but load DashboardComponent with it, so everything will work as before with a slight change:

```
localhost:3000/myApp = MainComponent + DashboardComponent
```

So I guess I want to load my MainComponent and then dashboard on init. It'd be very nice if the URL changes automagically from index.html to /dashboard too.

I tried doing something like this in my MainComponent.jsx:

```
componentWillMount() {
  <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
  console.log("It works!");
}
```

But it does nothing, I think the router from first example in Application.jsx just overrides it.

I think I might be doing something wrong because I feel like it's one of the most basic things with router but I can't find any answers and anything in documentation that would help me here. Any hints?

tl;dr I want `localhost:3000/myApp/index.html` to redirect me `localhost:3000/dashboard` when app starts (I think it should be enough for router to load what the right component).

Rerouting does nothing (there are no errors, but the route is not changing):

```
    <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" component={MainComponent} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardComponent} />
          <Route path="/users" component={UsersComponent} />
          <Route path="/admin" component={AdminComponent} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={ () => <Redirect to={DashboardComponent} /> } />
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `<Route path="/" component={DashboardComponent} />`?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using react-router v.4
I believe you can just create a route that renders a redirect component.
`<Route exact path='/' component={ () => <Redirect to={Dashboard} /> } />`

Comment: @daniel It will load only DashboardComponent without MainComponent, also all the other components will be loaded on top of DashboardComponent instead of MainComponent if I understand routing correctly.

Comment: @MEnf can't get it to work, check edited question. I think I have some logic issue here because others don't seem to have this kind of problems. Documentation doesn't explain my case at all too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should wrap your routes with the `MainComponent` and wrap in [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) and allow `'/'` to show `DashboardComponent`

```
<Router history={history}>
  <MainComponent>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminComponent} />
    </Switch>
  </MainComponent>
</Router>
```

Or if you do not want `'/'` to show the dashboard then you would use [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect):

```
<Router history={history}>
  <MainComponent>
    <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminComponent} />
    </Switch>
  </MainComponent>
</Router>
```

**Please Note:** You will need to put `this.props.children` in the `render` method of `MainComponent`.

---

**Alternatively**, you could put the `<Switch>...</Switch>` inside your `MainComponent`:

*Router*

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
    <MainComponent />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

*MainComponent*

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {

      return <span>
          //Navigation content here....

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardComponent} />
          <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersComponent} />
          <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </span>

    }

}
```

Useful Links:

- Switch: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch
- Redirect: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: I tried your first approach using Switch and Redirect and I'm pretty much sure the problem is my URL. My app is at: `http://localhost/myApp/index.html`, I feel like `Redirect exact from="/"` doesn't apply for that URL, is that correct? How should I fix it? It works as before, everything is fine but on ap init it just loads MainComponent without DashboardComponent & there is no redirect.

Comment: You should be using a bundler like `webpack` and `webpack-dev-sever` for your development which would host it at a port e.g. `localhost:8080` and then `'/'` would be correct. I don't think you are going to get it to work for the full path to your `index.html`. Are you passing a `history` object to `Router`? See docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router. If you cannot get your URL to be a port then perhaps try using `HashRouter`.